# how to log VBA macro errors and exceptions in access database?

Tags: ms-access, syntax, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble to log the VBA Macro errors into access database. 
How can you log the exact errors in VBA?

Comment: In your error handling procedure you can insert a record into the database.

Comment: How to get the exact error which is being thrown by the macro?

Comment: Via the Err object; Err.Description etc

Comment: Thanks blckbird and Alex K. I invoked the err.description and number inside the error handling procedure and it worked like a charm. :)